# .NET Assembly Method Loads

Tags: .net

How can I check which methods are called during a .NET application startup?
I do not have the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the assembly images are unsigned, the easiest thing to do would be to use the [EQATEC Tracer](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/tracer) to instrument the assemblies, then start the tracer, start the application, and then stop logging to the tracer.  It gives you granular control over what classes and even what methods are traced, so you can focus only on what you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is the usual tool for inspecting .NET code. But you should check any legal implications of disassembling an application's code.

Comment: I do not want to dissassemble. Just to know the sequence of methods that are called.

Comment: well, when you disassemble the main routine you will see which methods are called...!

Answer (score 0):

If the library/ application is a Microsoft one, please note that it is possible to get the .net source code. You can then debug into the corresponding .net code from VS.

Check out the link: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/default.mspx